# Segmentation fault: 11 - Where is it?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am compiling a program with gcc and when I run `a.out` I get this error:

> Segmentation fault: 11

I think it has to do with `Board::display`, but I don't see anything wrong with it..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const bool WHITE = 0;
const bool BLACK = 1;

//-----------------------------

class Piece
{
public:
    // constructors
    Piece();
    Piece(bool color);

    // functions
    char getColor()  const {return color; }
    bool getSymbol() const {return symbol;}

protected:
    bool color;
    char symbol;
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Piece & piece)
{
    out << piece.getSymbol();
    return out;
}

Piece::Piece() { }

Piece::Piece(bool color)
{
    this->color = color;
}

//-----------------------------

class King : public Piece
{
public:
    King(bool color);
};

King::King(bool color) : Piece(color)
{
    this->symbol = 'K';
}

//-----------------------------

class Tile
{
public:
    // constructors/destructors
    Tile();
    Tile(Piece piece, int row, int col);

    // functions
    bool  getColor()  const {return color;}
    void display();

private:
    Piece piece;
    int row, col;
    bool color;

};

Tile::Tile() { }

Tile::Tile(Piece piece, int row, int col)
{
    this->row = row;
    this->col = col;
}

void Tile::display()
{
    if (getColor() == BLACK)
        {
            if (piece.getColor() == BLACK)
                cout << "\E[30;47m " << piece << " \E[0m";
            else
                cout << "\E[37;47m " << piece << " \E[0m";
        }
        else
        {
            if (piece.getColor() == BLACK)
                cout << "\E[30;41m " << piece << " \E[0m";
            else
                cout << "\E[37;41m " << piece << " \E[0m";
        }
}

//---------------------------

class Board
{
public:
    // constructor
    Board();

    // functions
    void display();

private:
    Tile *tiles[8][8];
};

Board::Board()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
        for(int c = 8; c < 8; c++)
            tiles[r][c] = new Tile(King(BLACK), r, c);
}

void Board::display()
{
    for (int r = 7; r >= 0; r--)
    {
        for(int c = 7; c >= 0; c--)
            tiles[r][c]->display();
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//---------------------------

int main() 
{
    Board board;

    board.display();
}
```

Comment: People found the source of this particular segfault in the answers below.  But next time this happens, try firing up a debugger (like gdb) to locate the place in the code it happens.  I bet if you were looking at the exact line, you would have caught the error in the loop.

Answer (score 6):

In `Board::display()`, `r++` should be `r--`, and ditto for `c++`.

If (like me) you prefer unsigned variables for array indices, you would write the loop like this:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i)
{
    array[N - 1 - i] = something();
}
```

Or, if you find that to cumbersome but you still really don't like `<=`  and prefer iterator-style "not-equals" termination (like me), you can stick with unsigned types and say:

```
for (std::size_t i = N; i != 0; --i)
{
    array[i - 1] = anotherthing();
}
```

---

Your next mistake is to store a polymorphic object by **value** of the base. That can't work! Instead, you might want to save a *pointer* (or reference). While we're at it, it's time for you to learn constructor initializer lists:

```
class Tile
{
    Piece * piece;    // must be a polymorphic handle!
    int row;
    int col;

public:
    Tile(Piece * p, int r, int c) : piece(p), row(r), col(c) { }
    Tile() : piece(NULL), row(0), col(0) { }
};
```

If you store a polymorphic object by *value*, you end up **slicing** it. You could have saved yourself the trouble by making `Piece` abstract.

As you can see, you should also make sure the default constructor does something useful. In fact, I would argue that the default constructor doesn't actually make sense, and that you should just remove it.

Finally, I should add that the `Tile` class design is a terrible problem, because you don't manage the lifetime of the `Piece` objects, which currently just leak. If you were to manage them, you'd need to `delete` the piece in the destructor of `Tile`, but then you'd need to implement the Rule of Three, and now you realise that `Piece` needs a virtual destructor...

I'm realising that this is turning into a full-blown chapter of "How to do C++", so I'll stop now. I think we have several good books on our recommended list; please consult those.

Answer (score 3):

In `Board::display`, you are incrementing your variables in the loops instead of decrementing them.

---

You also aren't assigning `piece` to `Tile::piece` in `Tile`s constructor. (`this->piece = piece`)

Comment: Thank you, I did not see that.  However, after fixing it I still get a segfault.  I'm going to change it in the original question.

Comment: @AustinMoore: While you're at it, *condense* the question down to the part that matters! Use a debugger to figure out where the code breaks, and *then* post a question.

Comment: @AustinMoore: Please stop. Take out a good book on C++, sit down with a cup of coffee for several hours, and do learn more about the basics of the object model, inheritance and virtual functions. This is truly an educational task *far* beyond a StackOverflow question. We're very happy to help out with *questions*, but we can't provide full language courses.

Comment: @Marlon: But the `Piece` member functions aren't virtual, and `Piece` doesn't have a virtual destructor, and `Piece` is stored by value, ...

Comment: @KerrekSB You are correct. After I read your answer I had realized how much I had overlooked. (I had already given your answer a +1 anyways. It's very complete!)

Comment: @Marlon: But I hadn't realised the actual problem until I read your edit! :-) Anyway, I'm afraid that my question is nowhere near "complete" as far as the OP's grasp of C++ goes, so I think we're in the situation now where the internet doctor has to say, "go see a real doctor".

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm sorry this has turned into a hassle.  Perhaps I do need to review the details of OO programming with C++. Now, what would be the proper course of action about this question?  Should I leave it on StackOverflow or delete it, as I have found no answer and its topic is leaving the scope of SO?

Comment: @AustinMoore: I'm not sure. You can leave it, and maybe someone else will post something else that's also useful. I don't see any harm in that. As for yourself, I doubt that you would enjoy debugging a larger project if you're not at home with the basics, so I'd recommend taking some time out to build something smaller while you're learning, and leave this larger project for later. It shouldn't take too long, but you absolutely must be familiar with the basics before you move on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Surely you mean:

```
for (int r = 7; r >= 0; r--)
{
    for(int c = 7; c >= 0; c--)
```

to be

```
for (int r = 6; r > 0; r--)
{
    for(int c = 6; c > 0; c--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is just a typo the line:

```
for(int c = 8; c < 8; c++)
```

in the `Board` constructor is wrong and will result in none of `tiles` being allocated with the ultimate result of "bad" things happening when you try to use them.

Change it to:

```
for(int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
```

At some point you'll want to delete these although a better option might to be not use pointers at all in this case, just `Tile tiles[8][8];` or a `vector<vector<Tile> > tiles`.